# ZF2 Form Hydration with multiple objects and fieldsets

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm struggling trying to work out how to edit multiple models with a single form.

I have a database table called Teams and a doctrine entity associated with this table.  I create a form as below:

My team fieldset:

```
class TeamFieldset extends AbstractFieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('Team')
            ->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($this->getObjectManager(),'Application\Model\Entities\Team'))
            ->setObject(new Team())
            ->setLabel('Team');

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Hidden',
            'name' => 'id',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Team name',
            ),
        ));

        // ….  more fields go here
    }


    /**
     * Implement InputFilterProviderInterface
     */
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        // …. input filter implementation goes here.
    }
}
```

My team form:

```
class TeamForm extends AbstractAdminForm
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->setName('team-form')
            ->add(array(
                'type' => 'TeamFieldset',
                'name' => 'Team',
                'options' => array(
                     'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
                ),
            )
        );

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Save Team',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'btn-primary',
                'type' => 'submit',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

And in my controller:

```
public function editTeamAction()
{
    $team = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Application\Model\Entities\Team',$this->params()->fromRoute('team_id'));

    $formManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('FormElementManager');
    $form = $formManager->get('Application\Form\Team\TeamForm');
    $form->setAttribute('action',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $form->bind($team);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->persist($team);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
            $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin/leagues/league/team',array('league_id' => $team->getLeague()->getId(),'team_id' => $team->getId()));
        }
    }

    return array(
        'team' => $team,
        'form' => $form
    );
}
```

So far this is all fine and works great.

Now, I also have a legacy database with another Teams table in it.  I'd like the user to be able to edit both via the same form.

I don't use doctrine for the legacy database, but this is irrelevant and I can soon pull the appropriate record out into an array and then create a fieldset with an array hydrator for it.

However, you call the bind function on a form, not on a fieldset.  So how do I bind data to each fieldset with this single bind operation on the form?

If there were a bind operation on a fielset it wouldn't be an issue, I could pull each fieldset from the form and bind with appropriate object.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

:wq

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\Aggregate\AggregateHydrator`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/Hydrator/Aggregate/AggregateHydrator.php)

[The documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.aggregate.html) states

> You typically want to use an aggregate hydrator when you want to hydrate or extract data from complex objects that implement multiple interfaces, and therefore need multiple hydrators to handle that in subsequent steps.